# Getting "System error 1067" when installing OpenSSH

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, openssh

I try to install [this OpenSSH package](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Deploy-Win32-OpenSSH) on windows Server 2008 R2.
I applied all steps (except the firewall one) and all passed succesfully.

When I try this command

> net start sshd

I get this error:

> The SSHD service is starting. The SSHD service could not be started.
>
> A system error has occurred.
>
> System error 1067 has occurred.
>
> The process terminated unexpectedly.

What could be the problem?
I couldn't find any log file.
The Security in Windows' Event Viewer only says:

```
The SSHD service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).
```

When running in debug mode I get this:

--

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win32\OpenSSH-Win32/sshd_config

debug2: parse_server_config: config C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win32\OpenSSH-Win32/sshd_config len 256

debug3: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win32\OpenSSH-Win32/sshd_config:50 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

debug3: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win32\OpenSSH-Win32/sshd_config:115 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server

debug3: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win32\OpenSSH-Win32/sshd_config:123 setting PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

[Build Nov  9 2015 22:18:33]

debug3: getpwnam: username [sshd]

debug3: getpwnam: system dir [C:\Windows\system32]

debug3: getpwnam: shell path [C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe]

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_private: No such file or directory

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

Could not load host key: ssh_host_rsa_key

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_private: No such file or directory

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

Could not load host key: ssh_host_dsa_key

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_private: No such file or directory

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

Could not load host key: ssh_host_ecdsa_key

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_private: No such file or directory

debug1: _open() returned error, errno [2]

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

Could not load host key: ssh_host_ed25519_key

Disabling protocol version 2. Could not load host key

sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

--

You can see more details on the XML below.

Note:

- I skipped the Firewall step since the firewall is not running.
- It seems that I generated the keys successfully (I got no errors and I see two files in `C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh` folder: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub - see the output below)
- There's no antivirus installed on this host
- I tried to install both 32bit and 64bit packages (same error on
  both).
- My machine is 64bit running on VMware.
- I installed it as an administrator using "local system account"

These are the XML details from the Event Viewer:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          12/25/2015 12:17:53 PM
Event ID:      7034
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WINSXXX
Description:
The SSHD service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7034</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-25T10:17:53.073482000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>20007</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="468" ThreadID="4180" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>WINSXXX</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">SSHD</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">2</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Output of generating keys:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win32\OpenSSH-Win32\ssh-keygen.exe
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa):
C:\Users\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:POHEtRE0YZGfFqcxjkt8x9znhJsm+MvCuhFCUR9bYxg Administrator@WINSXXX
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|      ....EB+    |
|       o +oO+..  |
|      . +.++ X o |
|     . + .+ B = +|
|      . S. = . =.|
|       . oo . + .|
|        .. . o   |
|         .o..    |
|        oo .o.   |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

C:\Users\Administrator>

Comment: try to run the server in debug mode from command-line. Use the `-Dddd` switches to follow the log and see where does it fail and why.

Comment: Thanks. How do you do it? What's the full syntax? Can't find this switch

Comment: I would tell you on Unix, but I have no idea where is it installed on Windows. Trying `sshd.exe -Dddd` or `/path/to/sshd.exe -Ddd`  or some derivatives should do the job.

Comment: Thanks. I got you and it's working. I'm now updating the text of the question with the debug output

Comment: The failure is obvious. It can not load host keys. Did you generate them in the appropriate directory?

Comment: I got error messages like "key_load_private: No such file or directory" (but I applied the relevant step on installation). What goes wrong?

Comment: Yes I applied "ssh-keygen.exe -A" and it created two files in C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh folder: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33436/discussion-between-mosh-and-jakuje).

Comment: I updated the question with the output of generating keys

Answer (score 2):

I could finally resolve it.

The keys were not generated on the relevant folder.

If you follow [these instructions](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH), you have to change directory to relevant folder before applying step #3.

Comment: yes, the key generation was described in different way than you wrote. Anyhow great to have it solved.

Comment: What is the "relevant folder"? What command are you running in this folder?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to start the sshd service after following steps 5 and 6 in [the instructions](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH)

> 5. Setup SSH host keys (this will generate all the 'host' keys that sshd
>      expects when its starts)
>
>    - .\ssh-keygen.exe -A
> 6. Secure SSH host keys (optional)
>
>    - Start-Service ssh-agent
>    - download psexec [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
>    - launch cmd.exe as SYSTEM - psexec.exe -i -s cmd.exe
>    - register host keys in above cmd.exe
>    - ssh-add ssh_host_dsa_key
>    - ssh-add ssh_host_rsa_key
>    - ssh-add ssh_host_ecdsa_key
>    - ssh-add ssh_host_ed25519_key

Answer (score 0):

There is a Fix powershell file in the openssh zip file you download

This video explains it at 2:00 minutes:

https://youtu.be/gUOEaZb0gW8

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest [repository of OpenSSH](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-an-openssh-server-client-on-a-windows-2016-server/) and run the file `.\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1`. Reply YES to all questions.