# Getting “System error 1067” when installing OpenSSH on Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, ssh, openssh

I try to install this [OpenSSH package](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) on windows 7. I have followed these [instruction](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) and all passed succesfully.

I have looked into this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1017865/getting-system-error-1067-when-installing-openssh) but it is not clear what exactly was done to solve the problem.

I had a problem where I couldn't generate a key with

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win32>.\ssh-keygen.exe -A
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA Could not save your public key in __PR
OGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.sxfSDOzypn: No such file or directory
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: DSA Could not save your public key in __PR
OGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.juOzEtM1FK: No such file or directory
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: ECDSA Could not save your public key in __
PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.GJzXzpQzfK: No such file or directory
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: ED25519 Could not save your public key in
__PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.R26XZMokWU: No such file or directory
```

the solution I found [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1226). I had to create a folder in C:\ProgramData\ssh\

my Windows OS is Windows 7 32bit and I am using OpenSSH-32bit

When I try this command

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH>net start sshd
```

I get this error:

```
The SSHD service is starting. The SSHD service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

What could be the problem? Also, I don't see the sshd process in [services](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-error-1067-process-terminated-unexpectedly-windows-10-7-8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have found the right instructions for installing OpenSSH and
the right workaround.

The missing piece described in the answer you found is that step #3 and
all following steps must be run within the folder `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH`.

The `cd` command in that answer you found is just:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH"
```

This same problem is described in the bug report
[Getting “System error 1067” when installing OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/55), where it is claimed that the `cd` was added to
the installation instructions, although I cannot see any trace of it.

(I cannot test because I don't use OpenSSH, but hope that this will help in solving the problem.)

---

Your problem might be the same as described in the bug report
[.\ssh-keygen -A is broken, cannot make host keys](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1226),
where the solution was:

> you must manually go to `C:\ProgramData\` and create a folder named `ssh`

There is just this inconsistency that the developer in that bug report claims
that starting the service will create this folder, which doesn't
happen in your case.

There is also the question of what is your operating system.
If it's 64-bit Windows, you should have installed the 64-bit version,
and the installation folder would have been `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64`.
And are you executing everything inside a PowerShell session?

---

Note that **for Windows 10, OpenSSH is directly available** as an optional feature
which might work better than a third-party package.

Go to *Settings > Apps > Manage optional features* and add "OpenSSH client".
It installs to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` (and is added to PATH).
Uninstall first your version.

Comment: I did run net start sshd in the C:/Program Files/OpenSSH. I just have edited my question to provide clarity.

Comment: I added another possibility.

Comment: I have created C:\ProgramData\ssh folder to solve another problem and I am using OpenSSH-32bit for 32bit Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Did creating the folder change anything with the service start?

Comment: I have done all of those things before as the instructions told me. It seems I have done everything correctly but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried the same installation instructions on a different windows 7 machine and it worked... Something is wrong with the very first one I tried.

Comment: Something is wrong with the first windows7 PC I tried.

Comment: See my addition at the end of my answer, for a much less painful solution.